# Poor predictions on second dataset from trained LSTM model

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, prediction

I've trained an LSTM model with 8 features and 1 output. I have one dataset and split it into two separate files to train and predict with the first half of the set, and then attempt to predict the second half of the set using the trained model from the first part of my dataset. My model predicts the trained and testing sets from the dataset I used to train the model pretty well (RMSE of around 5-7), however when I attempt to predict using the second half of the set I get very poor predictions (RMSE of around 50-60). How can I get my trained model to predict outside datasets well?

dataset at this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BQOXffFYioCiPug2VcBZEZVD-u3y9bcl)

```
file = r'/content/drive/MyDrive/only_force_pt1.csv'


df = pd.read_csv(file)

df.head()

X = df.iloc[:, 1:9]
y = df.iloc[:,9]

print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)

plt.figure(figsize = (20, 6), dpi = 100)
plt.plot(y)

WINDOW_LEN = 50

def window_size(size, inputdata, targetdata):
  X = []
  y = []
  i=0
  while(i + size) <= len(inputdata)-1:
    X.append(inputdata[i: i+size])
    y.append(targetdata[i+size])
    i+=1
  assert len(X)==len(y)
  return (X,y)

X_series, y_series = window_size(WINDOW_LEN, X, y)
print(len(X))
print(len(X_series))
print(len(y_series))

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(np.array(X_series),np.array(y_series),test_size=0.3, shuffle = True)
X_val, X_test,y_val, y_test = train_test_split(np.array(X_val),np.array(y_val),test_size=0.3, shuffle = False)

n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2],1

[verbose, epochs, batch_size] = [1, 300, 32]
input_shape = (n_timesteps, n_features)

model = Sequential()

# LSTM
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=input_shape, return_sequences = False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

earlystopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience = 30, verbose =1, mode = 'auto')

model.summary()

model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = Adam(learning_rate = 0.001), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])



history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, epochs = epochs, verbose = verbose, validation_data=(X_val,y_val), callbacks = [earlystopper])
```

Second dataset:

```
tests = r'/content/drive/MyDrive/only_force_pt2.csv'

df_testing = pd.read_csv(tests)

X_testing = df_testing.iloc[:4038,1:9]
torque = df_testing.iloc[:4038,9]
print(X_testing.shape)
print(torque.shape)
plt.figure(figsize = (20, 6), dpi = 100)
plt.plot(torque)
X_testing = X_testing.to_numpy()

X_testing_series, y_testing_series = window_size(WINDOW_LEN, X_testing, torque)
X_testing_series = np.array(X_testing_series)
y_testing_series = np.array(y_testing_series)
scores = model.evaluate(X_testing_series, y_testing_series, verbose =1)

X_prediction = model.predict(X_testing_series, batch_size = 32)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your model is working fine on training data but performs bad on validation data, then your model did not learn the "true" connection between input and output variables but simply memorized the corresponding output to your input. To tackle this you can do multiple things:

- Typically you would use 80% of your data to train and 20% to test, this will present more data to the model, which should make it learn more of the true underlying function
- If your model is too complex, it will have neurons which will just be used to memorize input-output data pairs. Try to reduce the complexity of your model (layers, neurons) to make it more simple, so that the remaining layers can really learn instead of memorize
- Look into more detail on training performance [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/what-are-overfitting-and-underfitting-in-machine-learning-a96b30864690)

Comment: I split up a dataset into two separate files. One I used to train, but I also split that up through train_test_split, and then the other file is supposed to act like a whole different subject and dataset that I can predict from. From the first file I get good results from the train and test sets from train test split, but bad predictions from the second dataset. I don't get why the testing set from the first dataset predicts well but the second dataset does not when they're both unseen data in my model.

Comment: Do you shuffle your data before dividing it?

Comment: Yes but I’ve found that maybe I shouldn’t shuffle it? But when I don’t shuffle my results are very bad. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: Since its sequential data you shouldn't shuffle the sequences in itself but you should shuffle the complete sequences

Comment: If you don't mind, could you go into a little more detail into that? I think I understand what you're saying, but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the details and implementation.